# certificates profiles and xcode4

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode4.2

I'm having a lot of troubles uploading my app to the appStore.

I create the profile, download it and added to my xcode.

So, I have my project my scheme in archive mode.

I try to Build and get this mistake:

```
Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates
```

I think this is because I had a previous profile file that was incorrect, I deleted it but still having this error.

How can I solve it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, in project properties-> code signing I add the profile and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can see information about signed in 
Click Project on Left bar (Project Inspector), Select Project in central panel, Select BuildSettings tab, find Code Signin end setup your profile on each item.